# View model all some fields are returned as null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have this question i really stock in it, and i almost don't know what to do, this is my action for loading my model, and initialize it

```
  public ActionResult EditCredentials(int id)
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindById(id);
        var userViewModel = new UserViewModel()
        {
            UserName = user.UserName,
            FName = user.FirstName,
            LName = user.LastName,
            BirthDate = user.BirthDate,
            Phonenumber = user.PhoneNumber,
        };

        var allroles = UserRole.Roles;
        var roles = user.Roles;
        var userRoleViewModels = new List<UserRoleViewModel>();
        foreach (var item in allroles)// initialize All of Role view models
        { 
            var newViewModel=new UserRoleViewModel
            {
                Show = item.Show,
                RoleId = item.Id,
                BaseCoding = item.BaseCoding,
                IsActive = item.IsActive,
                RoleName = item.Name

            };

                foreach (var role in roles.Where(role => role.RoleId==item.Id))
                {  //if new Role Exist In userRole table, then apply is checked
                    newViewModel.ApplyPrem = true;
                    newViewModel.UserId = role.UserId;

                }
            userRoleViewModels.Add(newViewModel);
        }
        var userMainViewModel = new UserMainViewModel()// user main view model,  include two model: one "UserViewModel" and a list of "UserRoleViewModel"
        {
            UserViewModel = userViewModel,
            UserRoleViewModel = userRoleViewModels
        };

        return View(userMainViewModel);
    }
```

as you can see my view is IList this is my view

```
  @model IList<Mfr.Admin.Models.User.UserRoleViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditPermissions", "User", FormMethod.Post, new    
 {@class = "form-horizontal"}))
 {
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @*id*@
                        @(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].RoleId))
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @*Apply Perm*@
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ApplyPrem)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @*name*@
                        @(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].RoleName))
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @*base coding*@
                         @(Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].BaseCoding).HtmlAttributes(new { @disabled = "disabled" }))
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @*show*@
                          @(Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Show).HtmlAttributes(new { @disabled = "disabled" }))
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @*Active*@
                        @(Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].IsActive).HtmlAttributes(new { @disabled = "disabled" }))
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        }
 }
   <input type="submit" value="update" class="btn btn-success" />
```

This is the first line of post action

```
         public ActionResult EditPermissions(IList<UserRoleViewModel> model)
```

the problem is: when I want to post this Models, only applyperm field is modified and returned correctly, and all of the other fields, like userId RoleId and ..., in my view model are returned form view as null?
Does anyone know Why?
this is my ViewModel Definition

```
    public class UserRoleViewModel
    {
    public bool ApplyPrem { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public bool BaseCoding { get; set; }

    public bool Show { get; set; }
}
```

Just one thing that, when model is initializing in view and iterating through  for in my view, it is loaded completely without any problem, but the problem is begins when I want to post this function in my controller post action.
Thanx in advance

Comment: Because the only successful control in your view is for `ApplyPrem`. For the other properties you use just `DisplayFor()` (which does not generate a form control), and the other checkboxes are disabled (disabled controls do not post back a value)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Stephend Muecke , you're right about this fields, but how about those fields that are initialized first when i loaded the view?, I dont have any editor for those, like userId RoleId And The Others.

Comment: Your server is not psychic. If you do not generate form controls in the view for the properties you want posted back, then they will be their default values. But you should only be including a hidden input for the ID property, and then you can get the other properties by calling the database again if you need them.

Comment: Oh Yes You Are right, Really Appreciate you're time @stephen-muecke